# Is is possible that cheap wifi repeater contains malware?

Tags: wifi, firmware

There are lot of very cheap wifi repeater on ebay ([example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/300Mbps-Signal-Extender-Booster-Wireless-N-AP-Range-802-11-Wifi-Repeater-EU-Plug-/381778383312?epid=2120967086&hash=item58e3c3d1d0:g:8WcAAOSw4shX36Ij)).

Could it possible that it have malware pre-installed?

Due to cheap production cost, the repeater must not have much computational capability but I wonder what malware could do if it was there.

Have anyone investigated on this already?

Comment: There has been a lot of news about this since Snowden. Some of it very recently: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/06/15/wikileaks_dumps_cia_wifi_pwnage_tool_docs_online/

Comment: Please tell me why I got many downvotes, I am new to this site. What did I do wrong? Is it off-topic?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but your phrasing is rather vague. "Is it possible" I think obviously yes, we cannot rule that out and it would not be particularly hard to do for someone who has the motivation. "Is it likely?" Under what conditions? If you are the embassy of a high-profile country and are buying from a local provider then you should take the risk seriously. For consumers buying from other consumers, why knows? I haven't seen any research but it would certainly be an useful answer to this question. Is that what you actually mean?

Comment: If it doesn't it likely soon will - http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/tags/v2.78

Comment: @wizzup if you hover over the arrows, it tells you the standard reason for downvoting. In this case, your question is either too undefined, or, as I mentioned, it lacks research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it possible that it have malware pre-installed?

It is certainly possible. It could also provide phone home and backdoor capabilities, man in the middle, or any other type of exploit that may make sense. It can easily perform much the same function as the [LAN Turtle](https://lanturtle.com/).

> Due to cheap production cost, the repeater must not have much computational capability but I wonder what malware could do if it was there.

First, how much computational power is actually needed? Since E-Cigs have been found with malware (see [here](https://www.geek.com/tech/hackers-use-e-cigarettes-to-transmit-malware-1703638/), [here](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/nov/21/e-cigarettes-malware-computers), or [here](http://nypost.com/2017/06/19/an-e-cig-can-hack-your-computer/)), certainly a Wi-Fi repeater has more computational power. I wouldn't think this is any sort of barrier to putting malware or an exploit on such a device.

Second, criminals who are looking to use some sort of malware/exploit in this fashion are hoping to gather information that will ultimately make them money. Specifically more money than they invest in the project.

It may be a bit of a gamble, but such criminals are sometimes willing to spend some money in the pursuit of a bigger payoff. For instance, there had to be some additional cost in getting malware on E-Cigs. Or as another example, "lost" USB drives in parking lots as an attack vector has been established as possible ([here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/11/half_plug_in_found_drives/) or [here](https://www.wired.com/2011/06/the-dropped-drive-hack/)) and has been used in at least one established attack ([here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/criminals-push-malware-by-losing-usb-sticks-in-parking-lots/)).

> Have anyone investigated on this already?

Not to my knowledge, but if you have thought of it then it is likely someone else has thought of it too.

Does this mean that all these devices should be avoided? Well, that is up to you to decide for yourself. Odds are likely very low that any of them do actually contain any sort of malware or exploit.